# Error using the DATEDIFF syntax

Tags: sql, db2, datediff

I'm trying to find the age of employees from the `SAMPLE` database using this code:

```
SELECT
    EMPNO,
    FIRSTNME,
    LASTNAME,
    JOB,
    BIRTHDATE,
    DATEDIFF(HOUR,BIRTHDATE,GETDATE())/8766 AS AGE
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE JOB LIKE '%R';
```

but I keep getting the error :

> "HOUR" is not valid in the context where it is used.. SQLCODE=-206,
>   SQLSTATE=42703

This is using IBM Data Studio 4.1.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using `DB2`, it doesn't support `DATEDIFF` or `GETDATE()`.  Instead, just subtract the dates and use `CURRENT DATE`:

```
SELECT EMPNO, FIRSTNME, LASTNAME, JOB, BIRTHDATE, 
    (CURRENT DATE - BIRTHDATE)/365.25 AS AGE 
FROM EMPLOYEE 
WHERE JOB LIKE '%R'
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff -- I honestly wasn't sure with the division -- 24 should have gone to the top, and yes, yours is correct.  Thanks.

Comment: Is it supposed to output a negative number? Because it does.

Comment: Okay. Now the age output is way off. For birthdate 1977-05-17 it outputs 1016 for the age. And how do you remove the decimal points so it outputs a round number?

Comment: @WildanSyahidillah -- now that you have the appropriate syntax, getting your desired output should be a trivial task.  Start with `CURRENT DATE - BIRTHDATE` and see what you get.  Then convert accordingly.

Comment: @WildanSyahidillah - note that this will give slightly incorrect results, as getting 'true' age is a non-trivial task.  How accurate do you need the results to be?

Comment: Subtraction of two dates in DB2 returns a duration of the form YYYYMMDD, not a number of days.

Comment: @Charles -- thanks for the clarification -- I haven't used DB2 in over a decade and my main point to the OP was the syntax being used was incorrect -- DB2 does not have `datediff` or `getdate` functions...

Answer (score 0):

In DB2, the results of subtracting two dates is a duration in the form `YYYYMMDD'
So for instance, today April 23, 2015 the following:

```
select current_date - '1972-02-24' as myage
from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

returns: 430128
Years = 43
Months = 1
Days = 28

So what you want is:

```
SELECT EMPNO, FIRSTNME, LASTNAME, JOB, BIRTHDATE, 
    int((CURRENT DATE - BIRTHDATE) / 10000) AS AGE 
FROM EMPLOYEE 
WHERE JOB LIKE '%R'
```

Comment: And today on April 24, 2015 the example query returns 430200.  43 years, 2 months, zero days.  Duration is a bit harder to work with.  But it's more precise..